# What is the relevance of -sticky in case of a menubar

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

What is the relevance of -sticky in case of a menubar?

Seen so many examples online that use -sticky "news" with menu frames as below:

```
frame .t.frmMnu -bd 2 -relief raised
grid config .t.frmMnu -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 1 -rowspan 1 -sticky "news"
```

instead of

```
grid config .t.frmMnu -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 1 -rowspan 1
```

I don't see any difference when I resize the main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-sticky` value is probably being set to that value because the author always uses that value. For a menubar, it is probably not a good choice, as the places where you click to pop down a menu shouldn't normally become wider on any common desktop platform. Much better is installing a menu as the menubar for the toplevel using the toplevel's `-menu` option, especially as that's more portable.

Here's an example of how to make a really simple `File` menu:

```
toplevel .t
.t configure -menu [menu .t.menubar]
.t.menubar add cascade -label "File" -menu [menu .t.menubar.file]
.t.menubar.file add command -label "Open" -command { doTheOpen }
.t.menubar.file add command -label "Save" -command { doTheSave }
.t.menubar.file add separator
.t.menubar.file add command -label "Quit" -command { doTheQuit }
```

It's missing things like underlines, accelerators, implementations of the commands, etc.

Comment: Is it also possible to add background colors to the menu commands.
Currently, main menu is displayed in a different (but preferable) color than that of the menu commands Open/Save/Quit

Answer (score 1):

You’re not seeing any difference because the widget hasn’t been told to grow. Try this with / without the `-sticky` option:

```
toplevel .t
frame .t.frmMnu -bd 2 -relief raised -width 20 -height 10
grid .t.frmMnu -sticky news
grid columnconfigure .t .t.frmMnu -weight 1
```

`grid columnconfigure` and `grid rowconfigure` are used to set the growth rate of columns / rows in the grid: as the cells grow, the widgets hang on to the edges they have been told to stick to.